# Mapping data to a variable not working Firebase-SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, mvvm, viewmodel

i have data in my vm, but i cannot map that data to the @published variable for an unknown reason. all the keys are the same, and the data is correct.

**Model:**

```
struct Cars: Identifiable, Codable {
    
    let brand: String?
    let driverTrain: String?
    let engine: String?
    let fuel: String?
    let horsePower: String?
    let model: String?
//    let photo: String?
    let price: String?
    let topSpeed: String?
    let transmission: String?
    let trim: String?
    let year: String?
    let carID: String
        
        var id: String {
            return carID
        }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case brand = "Brand"
        case driverTrain = "Driver train"
        case engine = "Engine"
        case fuel = "Fuel"
        case horsePower = "HorsePower"
        case model = "Model"
//        case photo = "Photo"
        case price = "Price"
        case topSpeed = "Top Speed"
        case transmission = "Transmission"
        case trim = "Trim"
        case year = "Year"
        case carID = "id_cars"
    }
}
```

**View Model:**

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseFirestore


class AssetsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cars = [Cars]()
    
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
        print("Fetching data...")
        db.collection("Cars").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents found")
                return
            }
            print("Found \(documents.count) documents")
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.cars = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> Cars in
                    let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
//                    print("Data for document \(queryDocumentSnapshot.documentID): \(data)")
                    
                    let brand = data["Brand"] as? String
                    let driverTrain = data["Driver train"] as? String
                    let engine = data["Engine"] as? String
                    let fuel = data["Fuel"] as? String
                    let horsePower = data["HorsePower"] as? String
                    let model = data["Model"] as? String
                    let price = data["Price"] as? String
                    let topSpeed = data["Top Speed"] as? String
                    let transmission = data["Transmission"] as? String
                    let trim = data["Trim"] as? String
                    let year = data["Year"] as? String
                    let carID = data["id_cars"] as? String ?? ""
                    
                    let car = Cars(brand: brand, driverTrain: driverTrain, engine: engine, fuel: fuel, horsePower: horsePower, model: model, price: price, topSpeed: topSpeed, transmission: transmission, trim: trim, year: year, carID: carID)
//                    print("Created car: \(car)")
                    
                    return car
                }
            }
            print (self.cars)

        }
    }
}
```

photos of the firebase will be providided

I have putting checking if all the keys are the same, if the data is actually running through (the data is perfect and works when i print it, but i just cannot get it into the variable) and ive tried to put it on Dispatch.Queue.Async

Comment: can you show the code where and how you call `fetchData()`. Also how you declare/use your view model `AssetsViewModel`.
Note that your `print(self.cars)` should be inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async {...}` otherwise it will return empty. That is move it one `}` up.

Comment: Since you're defining `struct Cars` as `Codable`, you don't need to map the fields one-by-one....Try: `self.cars = documents.compactMap { document in do { let car = try document.data(as: Cars.self) return car } catch { print (error) return nil }` This is more robust. See https://peterfriese.dev/posts/swiftui-firebase-fetch-data for a full explanation.